# NSDate memory leak

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, nsdate

I have searched SO among other fora for the answer to this, but whatever I try, it does not seem to get rid of my memory leak. Does anybody have any suggestions?

I get a memory leak of 16 bytes per NSDate in my ViewController every time I present it.

```
-(void)initialise:(id)sender withDate:(NSDate *)date withMinimumDate:(NSDate *)minimum {
    delegate = sender;
    self.originalDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    self.originalDate = date;

    self.minimumDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    self.minimumDate = minimum;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.originalDate release];
    [self.minimumDate release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I have tried releasing and/or making the NSDates nil before allocating them for the first time, and setting them to nil in the dealloc method.

They are declared as nonatomic and retained properties in the Header.

Have I missed something basic here or is there a more complex answer?

Comment: are you using ARC or manual memory management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing an `alloc`/`init` of a `NSDate` for `originalDate`, but then immediately abandoning it and setting it equal to the `date` parameter, possibly leaking the `NSDate` you created. You're doing this with `minimumDate`, too.

At a minimum, remove those two lines that do the `alloc`/`init` of the two respective `NSDate` objects that you subsequently abandon in favor for the parameters to the `initialise` method.

---

By the way, this problem (and the `dealloc` problem) would have been highlighted for you if you employed the static analyzer ("Analyze" on "Product" menu or press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>):

[image: static analyzer]

When writing manual reference counting code, the static analyzer is invaluable for identifying issues. You really should have a clean bill of health from the analyzer. You can click on the blue icons and it will often expand with the descriptions and arrows that I show in the above screen snapshot.

Note, this also highlighted the inappropriate use of `self.originalDate` (instead of `_originalDate`, or whatever the backing instance variable is) in your `dealloc` method. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, you [should not use accessor methods in dealloc method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6).

Comment: It seems the differences between ARC and MRC were getting me confused on this occasion. Many thanks kind sir.

Comment: @Ollie I'd encourage you to check out the static analyzer, which will identify these sorts of issues for you in the future. It's a good tool, and invaluable if doing MRC. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are creating references to objects that are never released.

```
self.originalDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];

self.minimumDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
```

Seeing as you instantly overwrite these properties with new values, you just need to delete these two lines (which are redundantly allocating `NSDate` objects that are never used) and your leak should go away.

You should also check whether delegate is properly memory managed too, as I see no release in `dealloc` for the delegate variable.

Comment: To your final point about `delegate`, you're quite right. But if he has a [retain cycle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-1000810), trying to release that in `dealloc` might not resolve it (because `dealloc` isn't called until the retain count of the object falls to zero, i.e. until the retain cycle has been resolved). Often it's best to ensure that the `delegate` property is `weak`/`assign`, avoiding the retain cycle risk altogether. It just depends upon how `delegate` was declared.

Comment: Yeah, it is likely to be assigned. I just thought I'd point it out in case it wasn't, because I see Ollie opted not to use property accessors, so it may have been accidentally not assigned.